# Grep: How to pass the correct arguments to grep for a binary file

Tags: grep

I need grep to search a roughly 10mb binary file for me. I am able get the results that I want, using searchbin.py (a grep 'alternative') with the command: 
'searchbin.py -p "38 04 00" test.dump'

This searches for "38 04 00" and returns the result(s), with their offsets.

I want to be able to do this with grep without having to use any pipes, and I have tried countless arguments with no success. Any further attempts would just be trial and error, but I am sure that somebody here can help me out.

Thanks.

Sample input using searchbin.py:

```
searchbin.py -p "FF 85 00" test.dump
```

Output:

```
Match at offset:        7448324       71A704 in  test.dump
Match at offset:        7448328       71A708 in  test.dump
Match at offset:        7448332       71A70C in  test.dump
Match at offset:        7448336       71A710 in  test.dump
Match at offset:        7448340       71A714 in  test.dump
Match at offset:        7448344       71A718 in  test.dump
Match at offset:        7448348       71A71C in  test.dump
Match at offset:        7448352       71A720 in  test.dump
Match at offset:        7448356       71A724 in  test.dump
Match at offset:        7452364       71B6CC in  test.dump
```

I want this to work with grep.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the assumption that the bin file you are referrring to is like the ordinary "a.out" type of file and that you are looking to the get the offset only. Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong and I will update my answer accordingly.

In Linux, we have **xxd** command that can be used to get dump or hexdump of bin files.

```
xxd -b a.out > binFile
```

The above command copies the bin file contents to binFile. Then you can grep the file for the required pattern. Example:

```
grep -e "00100111"
```

This will result in:

[image: grep result]

Also take a look at **objdump** command for a more detailed object file analysis.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using adb, and only grep is usable through adb.

Comment: You can pull the binary file to your host pc using the command: `adb pull /path_to_bin  /path_to_be_stored_in_host` and then do the above commands to get the result